# How to add HTML text in collapsingToolbar?

Tags: android, html, text, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I am working with collapsingToolbar I want to add HTML text but I am not able to do that.

Below I had implement but it's not working.

```
 private void initCollapsingToolbar() {
    final CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbar =
            (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);

    AppBarLayout appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.appbar);
    appBarLayout.setExpanded(true);

    //now that you have access to your toolbar, set the directions.
    collapsingToolbar.setExpandedTitleGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    collapsingToolbar.setCollapsedTitleGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
    String part1 = " asdasd ";
    String part2 = "Hi";
    SpannableString str = new SpannableString(part1 + part2);
    str.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor("#ff0000")), part1.length(), str.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    collapsingToolbar.setTitle(str);

    // hiding & showing the title when toolbar expanded & collapsed
    appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {
        boolean isShow = false;
        int scrollRange = -1;
        @Override
        public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {
            if (scrollRange == -1) {
                scrollRange = appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange();
            }
            if (scrollRange + verticalOffset == 0) {
                String part1 = " asdasd ";
                String part2 = "Hi";
                SpannableString str = new SpannableString(part1 + part2);
                str.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor("#ff0000")), part1.length(), str.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                collapsingToolbar.setTitle(str);
                isShow = true;
            } else if (isShow) {
                String part1 = " asdasd ";
                String part2 = "Hi";
                SpannableString str = new SpannableString(part1 + part2);
                str.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor("#ff0000")), part1.length(), str.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                collapsingToolbar.setTitle(str);
                isShow = false;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

HTML is not getting implement on collapsing Toolbar

Comment: What do you want to do with HTML Text ?

Comment: @HeisenBrg I want to change text size and color of text